# Ubuntu terminal: How to change ctrl + c (interrupt) to something else?

Tags: unity, command-line, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity right now. I've changed my copy and paste keys to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> respectively.

The command I've used is this:

```
gconftool-2 -t str -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/copy "<Control>c"
```

Now I'm looking for a way to change the interrupt / kill process key from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to (for example) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. The problem is that I can't find the appropriate keybinding name for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't need to issue that command to do that. I changed my copy and paste keybinds to `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` by going to Edit > Keyboard shortcuts (or something like this, I'm not on Linux right now). I am also almost sure you can change the keyboard interrupt key there, if you can't, `ctrl + alt + C` might do a key interrupt now.

Comment: @mark kirby That's exactly what I want to do. Sorry if I hadn’t stated that clear enough.

Comment: OK, writing an easy answer now

Comment: Did some comment got deleted here? Because I think I'm missing something. But anyway, I meant that for `gnome-terminal`. If you go to `Edit > Preferences > Shortcuts` you can change almost every keybind there. Unfortunately, you can't change the keyboard interrupt, but after I changed my `copy` to `ctrl + c`, the keyboard interrupt became `ctrl + alt + c`. Hope that helps. I didn't write that as an answer because it doesn't answer your original question of how to change the keyboard interrupt keybind.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Personal preference or...?

Comment: @Tim it's just a personal preference.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your question better

Answer (score 22):

The key combo was changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> by default.

Also <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> is will kill the foreground task (same as clicking the cross).

To change the interrupt key to ctrl + I

```
stty intr ^i
```

Just change the "i" to any other letter you want and to see all terminal shortcuts you can run

```
stty -a
```

There is a very good answer explaining this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/160388/change-bash-shortcut-keys-such-as-ctrl-c), ignore the title and read the first answer.

Comment: That is a very helpful answer:  would you happen to know how to change the interrupt key combination in termial to `ctrl+shift+c`?  In previous iterations of terminal, changing copy to `ctrl+c` automatically did this.  But now it appears to be `ctrl+alt+c`.

Answer (score 0):

sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl

Change the section
// Map Ctrl to the left Alt key, Alt to the left Win key,
// and Super to the left Ctrl key.

whey it says "replace key " with

```
replace key <LCTL> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
```

On your shell configuration script write

stty intr 0xA2

Open Tweaks
On Aditional Layout Options -> Ctrl , mark "Map Ctrl to the left Alt key, Alt to the left Win key, and Super to the left Ctrl key."

Then on gnome-terminal remap the copy and paste to ctrl c and ctrl v that shoyuld be "Ctrl C" "Ctrl V"

Then move physically your keys to make sense

Comment: This is to make you keyboard works like mac. You will map AltGr-c as Ctrl-c like on your mac.