# Remap abort command in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, 17.10

I've changed my `alt` and `ctrl` keys in order to have the same keyboard layout as I do on my mac.

Ever since then I can't use the abort Terminal command (previosly without any remapping `ctrl+c`). In the Terminal preferences I can pretty much remap anything I want (Copy, Paste, New Window, etc.) however I could not find a way to remap the abort function.

I've already tried tweaking the dconf setting manually by `escape='<Alt>c'` but it didn't work either.

Is there any way to remap the abort command?

Comment: maybe [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620626/ubuntu-terminal-how-to-change-ctrl-c-interrupt-to-something-else) would help. Not sure if it is a 100% duplicate though.

Comment: It helps partially. I could remap it to `stty intr ^i` which would help but I don't know how I can use the `alt` key.

Comment: `stty intr "[c"` will work but then I can't paste correctly anymore and other  things are not working as planned.